# NSOpenPanel Remains Stuck with the Mouse Icon Spinning on OSX Yosemite

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, xcode8, nsopenpanel

Im testing out my OSX Application that is build on OSX Sierra on an Older version of OSX-Yosemite(10.10).The application works normally on the build system, but when it comes to the test system, there seems to be problem.

(I have changed the target to 10.10 and built the .app file.)

When the user clicks the 'open' button on the NSopenPanel,the spinner appears and the app gets stuck.

I have tried other applications like TextEdit and they work fine.
And yes,im using sheet type segue to show the alert box > User clicks a Button and the NSOpenPanel Appears.

What is going wrong? Please advice.

Comment: What is you app supposed to do when the user clicks on the button? Add some `NSLog`s to see where it gets stuck.

Comment: @Willeke It's supposed to populate a string array with files of specific format.How can I get the NSLog?

Comment: You can see the log in the Console App.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks for your help.But on restarting the system, the issue seems to be fixed.